# AWS Route 53 Zoho Email: Exception java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, smtp, socketexception, zoho

My Domain is in `AWS Route 53` Hosted Zone.

I am trying to send mail (spring-boot) by using ZOHO Mail host. where I am getting this error.

```
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2431) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.5.jar:1.6.5]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2418) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.5.jar:1.6.5]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.close(SMTPTransport.java:1394) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.5.jar:1.6.5]
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:476) ~[spring-context-support-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection or outbound has closed
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:1270) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:116) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.5.jar:1.6.5]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:142) ~[na:na]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2429) ~[jakarta.mail-1.6.5.jar:1.6.5]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

My Spring Boot properties configuration is

```
spring.mail.port=465
spring.mail.protocol=smtps
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
spring.mail.host=smtppro.zoho.com
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=
```

Comment: Is this issue has been fixed?

Comment: yes @nishantpathak, can follow below my answer

Answer (score 1):

port `587` is working.

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.zoho.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.from=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

*Message message = new MimeMessage(session)*;

***message.setFrom**(new InternetAddress(address))*  if the same as the mail you want to send through.

Or:

Parse the info you want to send from a file. works for me

```
String loadStringTemplate(String filename) throws Exception{
        String emailTemplateDir = FileSystems.getDefault()
                .getPath("your file path.html")
                .toAbsolutePath()
                .toString();
        return Files.readString(Paths.get(emailTemplateDir),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

I realise I get this error when I want to parse strings into Html content. *mimeBodyPart.setContent(htmlMsg, "text/html");*

Hopes this helps